# How to return DataSnapshot value as a result of a method?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I don't have much experience with Java. I'm not sure if this question is stupid, but I need to get a user name from Firebase realtime database and return this name as a result of this method. So, I figured out how to get this value, but I don't understand how to return it as result of this method. What's the best way to do this?

```
private String getUserName(String uid) {
    databaseReference.child(String.format("users/%s/name", uid))
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // How to return this value?
            dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

Comment: Like @PeterHaddad mentioned, the onDataChange method is asynchronous, which means that it will always return null. May I ask: Why do you need to return the user name? Why not simply use this name inside onDataChange?

Comment: As @PeterHaddad said, because `onDataChange()` method is called asynchronous, it won't work. Please see my answer.

Comment: Read this to understand why Firebase APIs are async: https://medium.com/@CodingDoug/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93

Comment: Read this to understand how to solve asynchronous database with one or more databasereference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720701/how-to-handle-asynchronous-database-with-firebase

Answer (score 125, accepted):

This is a classic issue with asynchronous web APIs. You cannot return something now that hasn't been loaded yet. In other words, you cannot simply create a global variable and use it outside `onDataChange()` method because it will always be `null`. This is happening because `onDataChange()` method is called asynchronous. Depending on your connection speed and the state, it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available.

But not only Firebase Realtime Database loads data asynchronously, but almost all modern web APIs also do, since it may take some time. So instead of waiting for the data (which can lead to unresponsive application dialogs for your users), your main application code continues while the data is loaded on a secondary thread. Then when the data is available, your onDataChange() method is called, and can use the data. In other words, by the time `onDataChange()` method is called your data is not loaded yet.

Let's take an example, by placing a few log statements in the code, to see more clearly what's going on.

```
private String getUserName(String uid) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Before attaching the listener!");
    databaseReference.child(String.format("users/%s/name", uid)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // How to return this value?
            dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", "Inside onDataChange() method!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
    Log.d("TAG", "After attaching the listener!");
}
```

If we run this code will, the output will be:

> Before attaching the listener!
>
> After attaching the listener!
>
> Inside onDataChange() method!

This is probably not what you expected, but it explains precisely why your data is `null` when returning it.

The initial response for most developers is to try and "fix" this `asynchronous behavior`, which I personally recommend against this. The web is asynchronous, and the sooner you accept that the sooner you can learn how to become productive with modern web APIs.

I've found it easiest to reframe problems for this asynchronous paradigm. Instead of saying "First get the data, then log it", I frame the problem as "Start to get data. When the data is loaded, log it". This means that any code that requires the data must be inside `onDataChange()` method or called from inside there, like this:

```
databaseReference.child(String.format("users/%s/name", uid)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // How to return this value?
        if(dataSnapshot != null) {
            System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

If you want to use that outside, there is another approach. You need to create your own callback to wait for Firebase to return you the data. To achieve this, first, you need to create an `interface` like this:

```
public interface MyCallback {
    void onCallback(String value);
}
```

Then you need to create a method that is actually getting the data from the database. This method should look like this:

```
public void readData(MyCallback myCallback) {
    databaseReference.child(String.format("users/%s/name", uid)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            myCallback.onCallback(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

In the end just simply call `readData()` method and pass an instance of the `MyCallback` interface as an argument wherever you need it like this:

```
readData(new MyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCallback(String value) {
        Log.d("TAG", value);
    }
});
```

This is the only way in which you can use that value outside `onDataChange()` method. For more information, you can take also a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)**.

**Edit:** Feb 26th, 2021

For more info, you can check the following article:

- [How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5)

And the following video:

- https://youtu.be/mOB40wowo6Y

Comment: Can this be achieved using Future interface and Callable? https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future

Comment: Hi Peter! It might work. I didn't tried yet but I will. I don't know if you know this, but here is an interesting [article](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93).

Comment: Yes, I saw it before since it is written as a comment in many places. But, I haven't read it, because I know how asynchronous works after reading couple of Q&A here. Anyway, I read it now and I guess it is better not to use `Future` since we need to use `newSingleThreadExecutor()` that creates another thread, and since the api is asychronous then it is already in a thread in java and we have to maintain this thread also and write more code.

Comment: @PeterHaddad Firebase client already runs all network operations in a background thread so I think you are right. There is no need for that. Thanks for providing me that resource!

Comment: @PeterHaddad just pass the value as a parameter, see my answer below...

Comment: @DragonFire You are just pasing `yourValue` as a parameter, you are not witing for the data.

Comment: Thank you for this amazing answer! You just ended my many hours of struggle and prevented many more.

Comment: @AlexMamo Once you have called the readData() method and supplied the instance of the callback, you get the value, right?  So how do I get that value and assign it to another variable, or compare it to another value of another variable, outside that readData() method?

Comment: getTotalAmount(new MyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(int value) {
                totalAmount = value;
            }

        });
This is what I mean, I have declared that variable 'totalAmount' globally, how then do I use it go get the value and use that value outside that method? such that the new value of the 'totalAmount' becomes the one we have acquired?

Comment: @willy I cannot do that outside the callback/readData() because the operation is asynchronous. You always need to wait for the data.

Comment: @AlexMamo you got it bro!

Answer (score 9):

Starting from the ["19.6.0"](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#realtime-database_v19-6-0) version, the Firebase Realtime Database SDK contains a new method called get(), that can be called either on a DatabaseReference or a Query object:

> Added DatabaseReference#get() and Query#get(), which return data from the server even when older data is available in the local cache.

As we already know, Firebase API is asynchronous. So we need to create a callback for that. First, let's create an interface:

```
public interface FirebaseCallback {
    void onResponse(String name);
}
```

And a method that takes as an argument an object of tye FirebaseCallback:

```
public void readFirebaseName(FirebaseCallback callback) {
    DatabaseReference uidRef = databaseReference.child(String.format("users/%s/name", uid))
    uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String name = task.getResult().getValue(String.class);
                callback.onResponse(name);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now, to read the data, you need to simply call the above method passing as an argument an object of type FirebaseCallback:

```
readFirebaseName(new FirebaseCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String name) {
        Log.d("TAG", name);
    }
});
```

For more info, you can check the following article:

- [How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5)

And the following video:

- https://youtu.be/mOB40wowo6Y

Comment: Awesome, keep it up ☻

Comment: @ChauhanAjay Thank you. You might also take a look at this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5) and this [video](https://youtu.be/mOB40wowo6Y).

Answer (score 3):

I believe I understand what you are asking.  Although you say you want to "return" it (per se) from the fetch method, it may suffice to say you actually just want to be able to use the value retrieved after your fetch has completed.  If so, this is what you need to do:

1. Create a variable at the top of your class
2. Retrieve your value (which you have done mostly correctly)
3. Set the public variable in your class equal to value retrieved

Once your fetch succeeds, you could do many things with the variable. 4a and 4b are some simple examples:

4a. **Edit:**
As an example of use, you can trigger whatever else you need to run in your class that uses `yourNameVariable` (and you can be sure it `yourNameVariable` not null)

4b. **Edit:**
As an example of use, you can use the variable in a function that is triggered by a button's onClickListener.

---

Try this.

```
// 1. Create a variable at the top of your class
private String yourNameVariable;

// 2. Retrieve your value (which you have done mostly correctly)
private void getUserName(String uid) {
    databaseReference.child(String.format("users/%s/name", uid))
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // 3. Set the public variable in your class equal to value retrieved
            yourNameVariable = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            // 4a. EDIT: now that your fetch succeeded, you can trigger whatever else you need to run in your class that uses `yourNameVariable`, and you can be sure `yourNameVariable` is not null.
            sayHiToMe();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}

// (part of step 4a)
public void sayHiToMe() {
  Log.d(TAG, "hi there, " + yourNameVariable);
}

// 4b. use the variable in a function triggered by the onClickListener of a button.
public void helloButtonWasPressed() {
  if (yourNameVariable != null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "hi there, " + yourNameVariable);
  }
}
```

Then, you can use `yourNameVariable` wherever you would like throughout your class.

---

*Note: just be sure you check that `yourNameVariable` is not null when using it since `onDataChange` is asynchronous and may not have completed at the time you attempt to use it elsewhere.*

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. This is not how thing are going on when it comes to asynchronous methods. Using this answer you'll have your variable `yourNameVariable` to be always `null` when using "wherever you would like throughout your class". You can use it only in your `onDataChange()` method. That's it.

Comment: @AlexMamo, your solution of defining an interface works nicely, but the following part of your comment is incorrect: "`yourNameVariable` to be always `null`."  For those looking for a more lightweight solution (that does not require defining an interface) this works well.  Once the variable has been retrieved and set, they can trigger any functions that need the result and know that the variable is not `null` (as long as it exists on firebase in the first place).  I have updated my example so you can see a concrete use-case.

Comment: Furthermore calling that method has nothing to do with asynchronous behaviour of methods. Calling that method is the same as using this line `Log.d(TAG, "hi there, " + yourNameVariable);` inside `onDataChange()` method. This means that when `onDataChange()` method is triggered you are calling that method.

Comment: @AlexMamo, the function was merely a single example.  You can do many other things that do not automatically trigger a funciton.  For another simple example, a button could be visible once the data has loaded and triggering the button would do something with the data you have fetched.  Again, your example is nice and I am not arguing that it shouldn't be the accepted answer.  That being said, your blanket statement (even the full one) of `yourNameVariable will be be always null when using "wherever you would like throughout your class".` is not true for all cases  ... (continued)

Comment: There are several cases in which you could use the value retrieved outside of fetching the data.  My point is merely that there is more than one way to skin a cat; some lighter solutions like the one I have posted may work better for some people, and your may work better for many others.  No need to get worked up, just sharing knowledge here.

Comment: A button can be visible once the data has is loaded only if you set the visibility of that button inside `onDataChange()` or if you use your own callback to wait for Firebase to return you the data. The second example is the same as the first one. Calling a method from within a method is the  same as having the body of that method inside onDataChange(). This has nothing to do with the asynchronous concept.

Comment: There are no cases in which you can use the value retrieved outside other that i already mentioned in my answer. You cannot return something now that hasn't been loaded yet. Your solution isn't a lighter one, won't work at all. Try to use the log statements and you'll understand what i mean.

Comment: @AlexMamo please see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/55741593/3904109 it can be done...

Comment: @DragonFire As I already commended there, you don't wait for the data you just simply pass that object as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a crazy Idea, inside onDataChange, put it inside a TextView with visibility gone 
`textview.setVisiblity(Gone)` or something,
then do something like

```java
textview.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class))
```

then later get it with `textview.getText().toString()`

just a crazy simple Idea.

Comment: and how can know when must get text from TextView (the method will be async)

Comment: unless the `textview` has already been destroyed. then it's just a crazy bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LiveData` as return type and observe the changes of it's value to execute desired operation.

```
private MutableLiveData<String> userNameMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

public MutableLiveData<String> getUserName(String uid) {

    databaseReference.child(String.format("users/%s/name", uid))
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // How to return this value?
            String userName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            userNameMutableLiveData.setValue(userName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });

    return userNameMutableLiveData;
}
```

Then from your `Activity/Fragment` observe the `LiveData` and inside `onChanged` do your desired operation.

```
getUserName().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(String userName) {
        //here, do whatever you want on `userName`
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is NOT a solution, just a way to access the data outside the method for code organization.**

```
// Get Your Value
private void getValue() {

    fbDbRefRoot.child("fbValue").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String yourValue = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            useValue(yourValue);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

// Use Your Value
private void useValue(String yourValue) {

    Log.d(TAG, "countryNameCode: " + yourValue);

}
```

**Another way of achieving result (but not necessarily a solution)**

Declare a public variable

```
public static String aPublicVariable;
```

Set This Variable Inside The Async Method

```
aPublicVariable = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

**Use The Variable Anywhere**

```
Log.d(TAG, "Not Elegant: " + aPublicVariable);
```

In the second method if the async call is not long it will nearly work all the time.

Comment: Tried something similar, value is passed even before data is fetched and ends up as null

Comment: This will keep updating for 1000 times, I'm working with a wallet which involves money. when I update by adding new amount to the current amount in the database. It keeps repeating the process and increasing the money till u quit the app because it's an Async Method so it's dangerous for working with numbers. I think for strings, u won't see the effects.